# _cgo_export.c:3:10: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found while running go test in VS Code after upgrading to mac OS Big Sur

Tags: macos, go, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to learn `select` statements in go from [learn go with tests](https://quii.gitbook.io/learn-go-with-tests/go-fundamentals/select). Just before this I upgraded macOS to Big Sur version 11.4. Now I'm trying to run the following tests in VS Code.

```
package racer
import(
    "time"
    "net/http"
)

//Racer ...
func Racer(a,b string)(winner string){
    startA :=time.Now()
    http.Get(a)
    Aduration:=time.Since(startA)
    startB :=time.Now()
    http.Get(b)
    Bduration:=time.Since(startB)
    if Aduration < Bduration{
        return a
    }
    return b
}
```

The test is

```
package racer
import(
    "time"
    "net/http"
)

//Racer ...
func Racer(a,b string)(winner string){
    startA :=time.Now()
    http.Get(a)
    Aduration:=time.Since(startA)
    startB :=time.Now()
    http.Get(b)
    Bduration:=time.Since(startB)
    if Aduration < Bduration{
        return a
    }
    return b
}
```

This is my go env

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/user_name/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/user_name/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/user_name/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/user_name/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.16.4"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="/Users/user_name/opt/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar"
CC="x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang"
CXX="x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch x86_64 -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/zc/4r25vdyj4cv3ynjx64633ly40000gn/T/go-build3724662099=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

When I tried to run this test using `go test`, it returned an error saying  `runtime/cgo ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libpthread.tbd' for architecture x86_64 clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

After doing some online research, I removed my command line tools using `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`, I restarted my system, an pop up appeared asking me to download command line tools again. I installed them. When I'm trying to test the code again using `go test`, it is returning an error `runtime/cgo _cgo_export.c:3:10: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found`. I did `xcode-select --install` but it is already installed. I didn't face any of these issues before the upgrade. May be something changed after the upgrade. Can I please get some help in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```bash
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include /usr/include
```